# There's 'NO' my wallet - Is it right grammatically?

Tags: articles, determiners

Here's the context.

I have gone on a trip and am staying at a hotel. I just used the swimming-pool and came back to my room. And I found out that I've left my wallet there. I asked the front desk to check if my wallet is there. In this situation, I'd like to say like this.

> 1. If there is not any wallet there, let me know.
> 2. if there is not my wallet there, let me know.
> 3. if there's no wallet there, let me know.

I'm comfortable saying #1, 2, 3. Then how about this?

> 4. If there's no my wallet there, let me know.

It's awkward because 'no' represents 'not any'. I would say #1 instead of #4. Am I right?

Comment: I would just say `Please let me know if you find my wallet there.`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> 1. If there is not any wallet there, let me know.
> 2. If there is not my wallet there, let me know.
> 3. If there's no wallet there, let me know.
> 4. If there's no my wallet there, let me know.

Sentence (1) is kind of ok, but we would rarely ever use this kind of sentence without a contraction of *is not*:

- If there is not any wallet there, let me know. (awkward)
- If there isn't any wallet there, let me know. (fine)

Sentence number (2) is grammatical but is extremely infelicitous. It's a bad sentence and breaks the general principles of information packaging in English. Generally speaking we don't use definite noun phrases in existential *there is* constructions. The phrase *my wallet* is definite in this example (we know which wallet the speaker is talking about). The main reason to use this type of construction is to avoid using **in**definite noun phrases as Subjects. This next sentence is not very good:

- A cafe is on the corner. (A bit awkward)

The reason is that *a cafe* is indefinite (we don't know which cafe we're talking about). The following sentence is better:

- There's a cafe on the corner.

But in the sentence:

- If my wallet is there ...

... the phrase  *my wallet* is definite. We don't have any reason to use a *there is* construction. If we do it sounds bad:

- If there is my wallet there ... (very awkward)

Sentence (3) is fine. Instead of a negated verb, it uses the negative determiner *no* (a determiner is one of those words that goes before noun like *the, a, this, my, some, any*) . The word *no* means *zero*. It goes with the noun *wallet*, it doesn't go with the verb *BE*.

**Sentence (4)**

Sentence (4) is different from the other sentences. It is not a good sentence, but unlike the others it is also *ungrammatical*. The reason is that it uses two determiners together. We cannot do this in modern English:

- *a my dog (wrong)
- *the his problem (wrong)
- *the some people (wrong)

Sentence (4) uses the determiners *no* and *my* together:

- *no my wallet (wrong)

The best sentence from examples (1-4), therefore is number (3). Example (1) is a bit awkward or pompous and (2) is very awkward. Example (4) is ungrammatical. However, if we want to make clear that it's *my* wallet that we are concerned about, it is best to just use *my wallet* as the subject of the clause:

> 5. If my wallet isn't there, let me know.

Answer (score 3):

**There is** generally means **exists** and used when you want to know **if any**, or **how many** things/objects exists

> Is there any wallet on the desk?
>
> How many wallets are on the desk?
>
> There is no wallet on the desk.
>
> There are five wallets on the desk.
>
> There are many wallets on the desk
>
> Is there anything on the desk? there is **a wallet** on the desk

Here you ask if something is somewhere or not, the question is **where is something**

> Where is my wallet?
>
> My wallet is here, my wallet is there, my wallet is on the desk
>
> If my wallet is there, let me know
>
> If my wallet isn't there, let me know